# Generating positions for SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am generating Y position for SKSpriteNode. I need to generate y position, but it should not be in the position previously generated image, should not overlap. How would I be able to do this in Swift in SpriteKit?

```
for _ in 1...3 {
        let lower : UInt32 = 100
        let upper : UInt32 = UInt32(screenSize.height) - 100
        let randomY = arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower

        obstaclesTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "levaPrekazka")
        obstacle = SKSpriteNode(texture: obstaclesTexture)
        prekazka = obstacle.copy() as! SKSpriteNode

        prekazka.name = "prekazka"
        prekazka.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(randomY))
        prekazka.zPosition = 10;
        prekazka.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width / 7, height: screenSize.height / 7)
        prekazka.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: obstaclesTexture, size: obstacle.size)
        prekazka.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        prekazka.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.obstacle
        prekazka.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ball
        prekazka.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask  = PhysicsCatagory.ball
        self.addChild(prekazka)
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand your code you would essentially like to have the y-position be one of 7 possible y positions?

Comment: I need to generate y position, but it should not be in the position previously generated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid *both* overlapping sprites and different positions you need to take the height of the sprite into consideration. *Something* like this perhaps:

```
let spriteHeight = 60 // or whatever
let lower  = 100
let upper = Int(screenSize.height) - 100
let area = upper - lower
let ySpacing = area/spriteHeight
var allowedYs = Set<CGFloat>()
let numberOfSprites = 3

while allowedYs.count < numberOfSprites {
    let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(spriteHeight))
    let y = CGFloat(random) * CGFloat(ySpacing)
    allowedYs.insert(y)
}

for y in allowedYs {
    obstaclesTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "levaPrekazka")
    obstacle = SKSpriteNode(texture: obstaclesTexture)
    prekazka = obstacle.copy() as! SKSpriteNode

    prekazka.name = "prekazka"
    prekazka.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y)
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to generate the sprite's position and then loop over all existing sprites in the scene and see if their frame overlaps with the new sprites frame:

```
let lower : UInt32 = 100
let upper : UInt32 = UInt32(screenSize.height) - 100

obstaclesTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "levaPrekazka")
obstacle = SKSpriteNode(texture: obstaclesTexture)

// Generate a position for our new sprite. Repeat until the generated position cause the new sprite’s frame not to overlap with any existing sprite’s frame.
repeat {
       let randomY = arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower
       prekazka.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(randomY))
} while checkForOverlap(prekazka) = true   // If it overlaps, generate a new position and check again

//Function to see if an SkSpriteNode (passed as parameter node) overlaps with any existing node. Return True if it does, else False.
Func checkForOverlap(SKSpriteNode: node) ->> bool {
   for existingNode in children {  // for every existing node
      if CGRectIntersectsRect(existingNode.frame, node.frame) {return True}  // return True if frames overlap
      }
return false   //No overlap
}
```

(Writing this from memory, so may need a bit of fiddling to work).

Another approach would be to generate and position all the nodes with physics bodies, and set the scene up so that all nodes collide with all others. Then allow the physics engine to handle any collisions which would cause it to move the nodes around until none are overlapping. At this point, your could remove all the physics bodies.